# cartesian product - SUM two columns in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to SUM two columns in the same table with different conditions on the SUMs.  The problem I am running into is trying to get the results into two different columns.  If I use this query I get the cartesian product.

```
SELECT SUM(p1.arc_baseEventCount)  AS 'Total Logger Event Count',
       SUM(p2.arc_deviceCustomNumber3) AS 'Total Connector Event Count'
FROM EVENTS AS p1, EVENTS AS p2
WHERE p2.arc_name = "Connector Raw Event Statistics"
```

When I run this query I get the expected result but the result is in two rows and not two columns.

```
SELECT SUM(arc_baseEventCount) 'total event count'
FROM Events
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(arc_deviceCustomNumber3)
FROM EVENTS
WHERE arc_name = "Connector Raw Event Statistics"
```

I know I am close but I am definitely missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `CASE` on this,

```
SELECT  SUM(arc_baseEventCount) 'total event count', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN arc_name = 'Connector Raw Event Statistics' THEN arc_baseEventCount ELSE NULL END) 'Connector Raw Event Statistics'
FROM    Events
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/121f2/2)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  SUM(arc_baseEventCount) 'total event count', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN arc_name = 'Connector Raw Event Statistics' THEN arc_baseEventCount ELSE NULL END) 'total_1',
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'Connector Raw Event Statistics' THEN arc_deviceCustomNumber3 ELSE NULL END) 'total_2'
FROM    Events
```

Comment: I Suppose ELSE NULL, should be ELSE 0, as NULL value would cause the entire sum of the particular group to be NULL

Comment: I am also trying to SUM all the numbers in the column (arc_deviceCustomNumber3) when the name is 'Connector Raw Event Statistics;.  I am not sure how the above sample helps out with that?

Comment: @user2070571 see the update, i'm not what is the column name for adding `arc_deviceCustomNumber3`. anyway you can change `name` into the original name of your column.

Comment: SELECT SUM(arc_baseEventCount) 'total event count', 
               SUM(CASE WHEN arc_name = 'Connector Raw Event Statistics' 
                THEN arc_deviceCustomString3 ELSE NULL END) 'Total Connector Count'
FROM Events

Comment: Okay I tried it and if I use ELSE NULL I get nothing returned if I use ELSE 0 a zero comes back.

Comment: maybe you have done something wrong, can you post some records? I posted a fiddle along with the question for some demostratiopn.

Comment: I can try.  What does the END do?  Also it does span multiple records right?

Comment: Your right I was doing something wrong, I accidentally had arc_deviceCustomString3 instead of arc_deviceCustomNumber3!  Thanks for all your help!  It works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery

```
select distinct sum(p1.arc_baseEventCount)  AS 'Total Logger Event Count'
, (select sum(p2.arc_deviceCustomNumber3) 
from events p2 on p1.something = p2.something
where p2.arc_name = 'Connector Raw Event Statistics') as 'Total Connector Event Count'

from events p1
```

Comment: Okay so the p1.something = p2.something has to be changed to a field that is the same in each row?